# Is there a way to resolve local module dependency when passing lambda function inline to AWS CloduFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a Nodejs lambda function that needs to be passed 'inline' into the AWS CloudFormation template.
This seems to be working with `'AWS::Lambda::Function'` using parameter `Code: ZipFile`Following the [official AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html)

However, my lambda function also has some local dependencies that I have currently stored in local subfolders. and is called and used by my lambda. They currently look like the following in my lambda code:

```
var dep = require('../config/local_dependencies.json');
var other_dep = require('./lib/other_dependencies.json');
```

Is there a way to pass those dependencies into the AWS CloudFormation template and used by my lambda function while it's stored inline in the template?

Usually, this problem can be solved using S3 Buckets by putting all lambda files/dependency there and pass the path to AWS template. Due to certain local constraints, I can not approach it that way. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can use multiple files for inline lambda code

Comment: @tianz due to the lack of any reply to this question, I have to say you are right at this point in time.